# Where do if put my Check Box if statement in Login Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, android-activity, google-signin

Hope you are well.
I would like to add a Check Box (I am 18+ Years Old) on my Login Activity (using Google Login) for my Android App.
It is working in a way: It continues to the Google Login Option (asking for your Email), then comes back to Login Activity again if not checked. Then shows the toast. So it works in a way.

I would like it to show the toast until the Box is Checked, then open the Email block to ask for your email.

Another problem is now it always returns to this screen when the app starts. But it does remember the user and doesn't ask for the email details again. I want it only once along with the Google Login.

What I'm really asking is please where should my check box if statement be? Please help.

It is now after:

```
  private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
```

Here is a Pastebin link just in incase:
https://pastebin.com/GPC2X3xJ

Here is the Login Activity:

```
 class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private companion object {
    private const val TAG = "LoginActivity"
    private const val RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN= 4915
}

private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var checkBox: CheckBox

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    auth = Firebase.auth

        // Configure Google Sign In
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        val client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.btnSignIn)?.setOnClickListener {
            val signInIntent = client.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
        }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    updateUI(currentUser)
}

private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
    //Navigate to MainActivity
    if (user == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "User is null, not going to navigate")
        return
    } else {
        val mCheckBox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.check_box_18)
        if (mCheckBox.isChecked) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Please confirm you are 18+ years old",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
        }
    }
}
private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                val user = auth.currentUser
                updateUI(user)
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                updateUI(null)
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but some help will really do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make validation inside the button sign in here

`findViewById<View>(R.id.btnSignIn)?.setOnClickListener { val signInIntent = client.signInIntent startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)}`,

if the checkbox is not checked you can show the toast,

```
val signInIntent = client.signInIntent startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)}`,
```

make this code inside validation